# UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController won't rotate in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController. I tried everything the community suggests regarding autorotation in iOS 6 without succes, finally I've decided to create a category to UINavigationController which didn't made any change to the oriantaion (although the functions did get called)

[image]

Then I've created a category for the UITabBarController like this:

```
#import "UITabBarController+ios6Rotate.h"

@implementation UITabBarController (ios6Rotate)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;;
}

@end
```

and got this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!
```

But all my orientations are supported?! hmm

Then I changed the code to this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

And that started my app upsidedown but still won't rotate. I don't understand what is going on. At this point I would like to see any kind of rotation in ios6, I don't care to which side but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a few hours to figure out. This is the solution:
For some reason the previos programer did something like this:

```
 [window addSubview:[someController view]];  // In the appDelegate
```

All I needed to do was to replace it with this:

```
  [self.window setRootViewController:someController];
```

Auto rotate orientation is back on!

Comment: Yes rootViewController is the way to go in iOS6. You should have figured out from the warning on the console.

Comment: Thanks! - The old method might be for backward compatibility with iOS 3.1, which doesn't have the 'setRootViewController' selector yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure you are adding correct `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. You could try calling the corresponding `viewController`'s orientation methods in your category.

e.g in `UINavigationController` category it would be like this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{  
  return   [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];   
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same code in my UINavigationController category which didn't helped (functions were called but no ordination change). Any idea how to implement that on a UITabBarController category?

Comment: You should get the visibleController in your UITabBarController category and call the corresponding methods of viewcontrollers.

Comment: What visibleController and what methods I should call? I really don't understand

Comment: In case of navigationController you could call corresponding viewController's method because viewController is pushed inside the navigationController, try the methods for TabBarController the way you have done before. I assume you have problem somewhere else. you are doing something wrong with your orientations.